# show the animated gif file until asp page load while redirect?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

When I click the redirect button, asp.net project redirect one html file And it show a loader (animated gif) to the user. Then it redirect to the particular page. Its works fine.

But now I not need the redirect page intermediate. When I Click the Redirect button, it show the particular asp page, and loader (animated gif) shows center in same page untill it loads. After the page loaded - loader (animated gif) has to hide. How can I do this?. Give a sample.

**C# Code -**

```
Response.Redirect("Redirecting.html?AvailResults.aspx");
```

**Redirecting.html Code -**

```
<body>
<div style='position:absolute;z-index:5;top:45%;left:45%;'>
    <img id="imgAjax" alt="loading..." title="loading..." src="images/ajax-loading.gif" style="width: 100px; height: 100px" /><br /> <br />
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    this.focus(); //focus on new window

    redirect = function() {
        var querystring = window.location.search.substring(1); //first query string
        var page = querystring.substring(querystring.indexOf('=') + 1, querystring.length);
        function toPage() {
            if (page !== undefined && page.length > 1) {
                document.write('<!--[if !IE]>--><head><meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="1;url=' + page + '" /><\/head><!--<![endif]-->');
                document.write(' \n <!--[if IE]>');
                document.write(' \n <script type="text/javascript">');
                document.write(' \n var version = parseInt(navigator.appVersion);');
                document.write(' \n if (version>=4 || window.location.replace) {');
                document.write(' \n window.location.replace("' + page + '");');
                document.write(' document.images["imgAjax"].src = "images/ajax-loading.gif"');
                document.write(' \n } else');
                document.write(' \n window.location.href="' + page + '";');
                document.write(' \n  <\/script> <![endif]-->');
            }
        }
        return {
            begin: toPage
        }
    } ();

    redirect.begin();

    /* ]]> */
</script>  
</body>
```

Comment: This code looks antediluvian! Checking for IE4! That came out in the '90s

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you can't remove the intermediate step AND show/hide your spinner on a different url (you would have already redirected by the time it loaded).  You need a page to load the ajax spinner.  I see two choices:

Option 1: go back to the way you were doing it (click redirect button, go to redirect page with spinner, then redirect to the final destination).  This is similar those "You're now leaving xyz.com" splash pages that forums often use...

Option 2: add an iFrame to your redirect page so you can both show/hide the spinner and load the destination page (in the iframe) at the same time.  (If you're redirecting to your own pages in an app or keeping the host the same, you should be able to avoid cross-site issues and ensure the destination pages don't contain frame-breakout scripts etc)

Here's what that might look like:

```
<div style='position:absolute;z-index:5;top:45%;left:45%;'>
  <img id="imgAjax" alt="loading..." title="loading..." src="images/ajax-loading.gif" style="width: 100px; height: 100px" />
</div>

<iframe src="about:blank" id="ifRedir" onload="$('#imgAjax').hide();" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:0px;"</iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ifRedir').attr('src', location.search.substr(1));
    });
</script>
```

I think it's always better for a child page in a frame to tell a parent frameholder when it's done loading (you could do this via window.onload and a "parent." call).  Without this type of interaction the page will load (and hide the loading spinner) before all pages assets (images) are fully loaded.

You could avoid this by removing the  code and instead using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ifRedir').attr('src', location.search.substr(1));
        setTimeout(function () { $('#imgAjax').hide(); }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```